# Create database schema from WSDL file

Tags: java, database, jpa, wsdl, schema

right now im accessing a soap web service using generated code from a wsdl file via wsimport
the objects generated by wsimport are quite complex

my goal is to persist these complex objects into a database
is there a way to have the jpa annotations generated?

if not, whats an appropiate approach for achieving my goal?

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be to create a seperate object (with corresponding jpa annotations) for your database tables, and copy the required values from your objects (generated by wsimport).
In this way, even if your structure of your wsimport object changes in the future, you will have less impact on your persistence layer.

Comment: thats probably correct, but as i said the objects and therby the model is very complex.. so just for an initial start i want this generated to save some time